# Let the boolean function F=AB'C+A'BC+A'BC'+AB'C' is equivalent to

Tags: discrete-mathematics, boolean-algebra

Let the boolean function  $F=AB'C+A'BC+A'BC'+AB'C'$ is equivalent to which of the following

1) B directsum C

2) A directsum B

3) C directsum A

4)A directsum B directsum C

Plz explain in details

Comment: Directsum refer to usual direct sum,  i don't know how to write directsum in language so i wrote in word

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pull out $C$ from the first two terms and $C'$ from the last two terms:
$$F=(AB'+A'B)C\, +\, (A'B+AB')C'\ =\ (AB'+A'B) (C+C') $$
Here $C+C'=1$ and $AB'+A'B=A\oplus B=(A+B)(A'+B')$ is the *symmetric difference* (or direct sum).

Comment: What is A directsum B,  in boolean algebra

Comment: For sets, it's $(A\setminus B)\cup(B\setminus A) =(A\cup B) \setminus(A\cap B) $.